# Cannot insert records to ms access 2007 with vb6

Tags: sql, database, insert, vb6

I have been searching around for the proper way of connecting into the database(MS ACCESS 2007) using VB6.0... The problem is it says an error that "SYNTAX ERROR IN INSERT INTO STATEMENT"

DECLARATION CODE:

```
Dim adoConn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim adoRS As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim conStr, sqlStr As String
```

CONNECTION CODE:

```
conStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.3.51;Data Source= " & App.Path &        "\curriculum.mdb;Persist Security Info=False"
Set adoConn = New ADODB.Connection
adoConn.ConnectionString = conStr
adoConn.Open
```

Here is the BUTTON code:

```
sqlStr = "INSERT INTO cur(CourseCode, Units, Days, Time, RoomNumber, Instructor, Course, YearLevel, Term) VALUES ("

sqlStr = sqlStr & "'" & txtCurCourseCode.Text & "',"
sqlStr = sqlStr & "'" & txtCurUnits.Text & "',"
sqlStr = sqlStr & "'" & txtCurDays.Text & "',"
sqlStr = sqlStr & "'" & txtCurTime.Text & "',"
sqlStr = sqlStr & "'" & txtCurDays.Text & "',"
sqlStr = sqlStr & "'" & txtCurRoom.Text & "',"
sqlStr = sqlStr & "'" & txtCurInstructor.Text & "',"
sqlStr = sqlStr & "'" & cboCurCourse.Text & "',"
sqlStr = sqlStr & "'" & txtCurYearLevel.Text & "',"
sqlStr = sqlStr & "'" & txtCurTerm.Text & "')"
adoConn.Execute sqlStr
```

THE ERROR IS FOUND IN THIS LINE OF CODE WHEN I CLICK DEBUG: adoConn.Execute sqlStr

YOUr help would be greatly appreciated as this school project is needed by tomorrow. Been sleepless for many nights. thansk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Escape the column names that match reserved words: `TIME` by enclosing in `[]`:

```
 sqlStr = "INSERT INTO cur(CourseCode, Units, Days, [Time], RoomNumber, Instructor, Course, YearLevel, Term) VALUES ("
```

You should also use paramaterized queries as what you have in vulnerable to SQL Injection. (Run with a ' in one of the textboxes)

Comment: Hi,  Thank you so much! I don't know how to thank you.. Thank you.. I also tried your advice on the ' thing. and it did show an error. once again. Thank you

Comment: @user3221896 spotted the other prob

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you are using duplicate value..

I mean yor are trying to `INSERT INTO` to 9 columns(CourseCode, Units, Days, Time, RoomNumber, Instructor, Course, YearLevel, Term), however, you are putting 10 values().
`txtCurDays` is duplicated.

Comment: Yes, it did show an error. Thank you. fixed it. Already working. Thanks to all the help guys. How can I close this thread? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That error indicates the generated SQL statement has an error in it.

Set a breakpoint on the line:

```
adoConn.Execute sqlStr
```

Then view the SQL query (print it to the immediate window or just examine it in the locals window).  Check for any syntax errors.

One likely errore in your SQL would be a apastrophe (') in one of your text fields.  You need to make sure you "escape" any apostrophes in your SQL statement.  You can do this easily by tweaking your code a bit like so:

```
sqlStr = sqlStr & "'" & Replace(cboCurCourse.Text, "'", "''") & "',"
```

Comment: Also, thank you very much for your help in the issue with apostrophes.. Thank you..